# Multiple background scripts in one command

Tags: command-line, scripts, background-process

I can run three scripts at once like this:

```
python script1.py ; python script2.py ; python script3.py
```

But when I try to run them all in the background, like this:

```
python script1.py & ; python script2.py & ; python script3.py &
```

I get this:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I also tried using only one ampersand at the very end, but that made only one process run in the background.

I want to launch them in one command because the scripts print to the screen continually, making it hard to enter new commands. How can I do this?

(The scripts don't have main() functions, in case your thoughts were tending in that direction.)

Comment: You are mixing the & used as "and" with the **command line** & (related to nohup) to put something in background. Not going to work. Put them in between ( )'s

Comment: Try `(python script1.py &) ; (python script2.py &) ; (python script3.py &)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right syntax is

```
python script1.py & python script2.py & python script3.py &
```

My reference is `man bash` in the `Lists` section:

> ```
> Lists
>    A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the 
>    operators ;, &, &&, or ||, and optionally terminated by one of ;, &, or <newline>.
>
> [...]
>
>    If  a  command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes
>    the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for 
>    the command to finish, and the return status is 0.
> ```